# Are inner functions automatically declared in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider a file `functions.cpp`:

```
// functions.cpp

void f1(){/* do something */}

void f2()
{
    f1();
}
```

I wish to use the function `f2` in a different cpp file, so I create a header file `functions.h`:

```
// functions.h

#ifndef F2
#define F2

void f2();

#endif
```

Now, the `main.cpp` file is where I call `f2`:

```
// main.cpp

#include "functions.h"

int main()
{
    f2();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this works fine, but I haven't declared `f1` in `functions.h`. So when `f2` is called, how does the compiler know about `f1`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Typo, sorry!

Comment: Notice that you won't be able to call (directly) `f1` from `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `main.cpp` is translated, an external reference is generated to the function `f2`. Roughly speaking, this means that the object file generated by the compiler contains instructions to call a function at a certain address, and leaves metadata telling the linker to fill in the actual address of `f2`. Separately, the compiler translates `functions.cpp` and internally resolves the reference from `f2` to `f1` and emits an object file containing the definition of `f2`. Then the linker, seeing both the object file containing `f2` and the object file requiring the address of `f2`, "links" them together into an executable. Thus, the caller of `f2` does not need to be aware of the declarations of any entities used by `f2`.

Answer (score 1):

`void f1(){/* do something */}` is both a declaration and a definition of `f1` and it is visible to `f2`. Source files are parsed top-down. So `f2` has all it needs and callers of `f2` don't need to know about `f1`.